# basic question in real analysis/Question about Schwartz spaces

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Define the Schwartz space by
$$ S(R) = \{ f \in C^{\infty} ; \displaystyle\sup_{x \in R} |x^{\alpha} \partial^{\beta f(x)}| < \infty\  \forall  (\alpha,\beta) \in N\times N \}    $$.

Let $f \in S(R)$ with $f(0) = 0$. Show that $f(x ) = xg(x), x \in R$, with $g \in S(R)$. This is a exercise of my book. He gives a hint : $f(x) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dt}f(tx) \ dt$. I am trying to write f as a Taylor series (my professor said this help), but i am getting anywhere. Someone can give me a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The premise $f(0)= 0$ is missing. I don't think the Taylor series will really help. Start with using the chain rule for the integrand.

Comment: @DanielFischer , thanks . Your comment allowed me to do the exercise. You helped me a lot. thanks ! (my english is terrible, sorry)

Comment: Great. Happy to help. (No, it's not terrible. It's rather decent actually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint:

$$f(x) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dt}f(tx) \ dt 
= x \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f'(tx) \ dt $$
The function $g(x):=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f'(tx) \ dt$ is smooth. The required decay of its derivatives at infinity can be verified directly: 
$$g^{(n)}(x)=(x^{-1}f(x))^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k k!\, x^{-1-k} f^{(n-k)}(x)
$$
where $f^{(n-k)}(x)$ decays faster than any power of $x$.

Related: [Quotient of two smooth functions is smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541046/) and the threads linked there.