# Show that $A$ is symmetric, with $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$.
>
> Show that if $A(\,{}^t\!A)A$  is symmetric, then $A$ is also symmetric.

My attempt:

If $A \in Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$,

We have : ${}^t(A^{-1})=(\,{}^t\!A)^{-1}$
Then :
$${}^t\!AA\,{}^t\!A= A{}^tAA
A\,{}^t\!A=(\,{}^\!tA)^{-1}A\,{}^t\!AA$$

This does not allow me to continue ...

I started with $A$ invertible for use after density. However, it may be a bad idea, what do you think?

Thank you

Edit : ${}^tA$ is the transpose of A.

Comment: What does $^tA$ denote?

Comment: @GitGud The transpose of $A$

Comment: What about $A^t$?

Comment: @GitGud In many countries they denote ${}^tA$. Like France

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Let me denote the transpose of $A$ by $A^t$. Since $AA^tA$ is symmetric,

$$AA^tA=A^tAA^t\Longrightarrow (AA^t)^3=(A^tA)^3 \Longrightarrow AA^t=A^tA.$$

That is to say, $A$ is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). Then use the fact that $A$  unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix to show $A$ is symmetric.

---

**Update:** Let me extend the statement to the complex valued case and add some details to the proof. To begin with, let me denote the Hermitian conjugate of $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ by $A^*$.

> **Claim:** Given $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$, if $AA^*A$ is Hermitian, then $A$ is also Hermitian.

**Proof:** Denote $B:=AA^*A$. As shown in the hint, since $B=B^*$, 
$$(AA^*)^3=BB^*=B^*B=(A^*A)^3.$$
Since $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are Hermitian, the equality above implies that $AA^*=A^*A$. This is due to a general fact: if $H$ is Hermitian and $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a function, then there is a natural way to uniquely define a Hermitian matrix $f(H)$. In our situation, $H=(AA^*)^3=(A^*A)^3$, $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

We have seen that $A$ is a normal matrix, so $A=U\Lambda U^*$ for some unitary  $U$ matrix and some diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. Then
$$\Lambda\Lambda^*\Lambda=U^*BU=U^*B^*U=\Lambda^*\Lambda\Lambda^*.$$
Since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, the equality above implies that it is real valued, so $A$ is Hermitian. $\quad\square$

Comment: @Nico: In contrast to your opinion, I think only this step is trivial in the whole argument, because other steps are based on certain facts in linear algebra but this step only needs direct calculation: $(AA^t)^3=(AA^tA)(A^tAA^t)=(A^tAA^t)(AA^tA)=(A^tA)^3$.

Comment: Arf, Silly me! Thank you very much. Very smart.

Comment: (I will accept your answer later because I think it deserve more that two upvotes)

Comment: @Nico: You are welcome. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @HuZhengtang I don't get $(AA^t)^3=(A^tA)^3 \Longrightarrow AA^t=A^tA$. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @GitGud: I am not clear about your background knowledge. Can you see if $S\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is symmetric , then there exists a unique symmetric $T\in M_n(\Bbb R)$, such that $T^3=S$?

Comment: That's not exactly true due to permutation of the eigenvalues. Modulo this, yes, I can see it.

Comment: @GitGud: It is exactly true. Please verify this fact by yourself.  Once you accept this fact, can you answer your own question?

Comment: @HuZhengtang You're right, I had missed something, thanks.

Comment: @GitGud: You are welcome.

Comment: @HuZhengtang Real normal matrices are unitarily (but not necessarily orthogonally) similar to complex (but not necessarily real) diagonal matrices. I think there is still a large gap between the last step in your hint and a complete solution.

Comment: @user1551: I don't think the gap is so large(as I claimed my answer is only a hint rather than a full solution). Let me denote the Hermitian conjugate of $X\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ by $X^*$. Then $A=U\Lambda U^*$ for some unitary $U$ and some diagonal $\Lambda$. Then $AA^tA=AA^*A=U\Lambda \Lambda^*\Lambda U^*$ is real and symmetric implies that $\Lambda \Lambda^*\Lambda$ is Hermitian, and hence real. I think you can complete the argument from here.

Comment: @HuZhengtang Can you please elaborate on the uniqueness of the cubic root of a symmetric matrix? I'm stuck proving it.

Comment: @GabrielR.: I will only provide a sketch. If $S$ and $T$ are real symmetric and $S=T^3$, then since $ST=TS$, for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $S$, the associated eigenspace $V_\lambda:=\{v: Sv=\lambda v\}$ it $T$-invariant, i.e. $T(V_\lambda)\subset V_\lambda$. Then with out loss of generality, we may assume $S=\lambda I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Now can your prove that if $T$ is real symmetric and $T^3=\lambda I$, then $T=\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}}I$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By diagonalizing T I can prove your last claim. However I can't figure out why you can suppose without loss of generality that $S=\lambda I$. Can you enlighten me about this?

Comment: @GabrielR.: I think I have explained in my last comment that restricted to any eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of $S$, $S$ acts like $\lambda I$ and $T(V_\lambda)\subset V_\lambda$. Maybe I should also have mentioned that the whose space is a direct sum of  eigenspaces of $S$.

Comment: Hi, @GabrielR., sorry for bothering. I found you also commented under [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/544088). May I know if you downvoted my answer? If so, since I have corrected the mistake in the answer pointed by you(and since that is an inessential mistake), would you mind canceling your downvote? I am sorry for being rude(I care so much about the downvote because it is the only downvote I received); if either you didn't downvote or you don't want to cancel it, please just ignore my message.   I apologize again for my rudeness.

Comment: @HuZhengtang Wow this goes way back... I did downvote it, but cancelled it now since it is correct.

Comment: @GabrielR.: Thank you so much for cancelling the downvote and for the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

By an orthogonal change of basis, we may assume that the singular value decomposition of $A$ is $US$, where $U$ is real orthogonal and $S$ is nonnegative and diagonal. Then the given condition implies that $US^3$ is symmetric. Hence $(US^3)(S^3U^T) = (S^3U^T)(US^3)$ (the credit of considering $(AA^TA)(A^TAA^T)=(A^TAA^T)(AA^TA)$ here goes to Hu Zhengtang), or $US^6U^T = S^6$. Since positive semidefinite matrices have unique positive semidefinite $n$-th roots, it follows that $USU^T = S$. Therefore both $U$ and $U^T$ commute with $S$, and in turn also with $S^+$, the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $S$. Consequently,
$$
A=US=US^3(S^+)^2=(US^3)^T(S^+)^2=S^3U^T(S^+)^2=S^3(S^+)^2U^T=SU^T=A^T.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here I only answer the question for case $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\Longrightarrow AA^tA=\begin{bmatrix}
\sim & a^2b+b^3+acd+bd^2\\
a^2c+abd+c^3+c^2d & \sim
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$a^2c+abd+c^3+c^2d=a^2b+b^3+acd+bd^2\Longrightarrow a^2(c-b)+ad(b-c)+(c^2+bc+b^2)(c-b)+d^2(b-c)=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow c=d\text{ or } a^2-ad+c^2+cb+b^2-d^2=0$$
But pay attention that we are in real numbers so squares can't be negative. Thus;
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=ad-bc\leq (\max\{a,d\})^2\leq a^2+d^2\Longrightarrow b^2+c^2=0\Longrightarrow b=c=0$$

Therefore $A$ is asymmetric.