# Conditions for "$AA^T=A^TA$ implies $A$ symmetric" to hold.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This claim arose in this question [Show that $A$ is symmetric, with $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737935/show-that-a-is-symmetric-with-a-in-m-n-mathbb-r/738474?noredirect=1#comment1543980_738474) where it is assumed additionally that $AA^TA$ is symmetric.

I'm considering weakening hypotheses.

Let $A$ be a **real** matrix such that $AA^T=A^TA$. This implies that $A$ is normal.

According to the spectral theorem (for complex-valued normal matrices), $$A=UDU^*$$ for some complex diagonal matrix $D$ and complex unitary matrix $U$.

I am not sure I can infer from here that $D$ and $U$ must have real entries. Nevertheless, if $A$ has real eigenvalues, then $D$ must have real entries.

- Are real eigenvalues sufficient to prove that $U$ has real entries ?
- Is there a way to circumvent the use of the spectral theorem ?
- Can you think of other hypotheses for the result to hold ?
- Is the claim " $AA^T=A^TA$ implies $A$ symmetric" true for any real $A$ without conditions on eigenvalues ? (**EDIT**: Answer is no.)

Comment: $A$ symmetric $\implies$ $A$ normal. Converse may not be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim isn't true. Take for example an orthogonal matrix $O$ so we have
$$OO^T=O^TO=I_n$$
and $O$ isn't symmetric.

Comment: What about the eigenvalues of $O$ ? Are they real ?

Comment: Not necessary. Take for example this matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}\\
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: For $2*2$ matrices, orthogonal matrices are either symmetric, or they have complex eigenvalues (their imaginary part is $|sin(\theta)|$). Is is true for higher dimensions? Can you disprove the stronger claim that if $A$ has real eigenvalues, then $A$ is symmetric ?

Comment: Short and sweet, Sami!