# Fourier transform of unit step function

Tags: distribution-theory

It is well known that the fourier transform for unit step $U(t)$ is

\begin{equation}
 F(U(t))=\frac{1}{j\omega}+\pi \delta(\omega)
\end{equation}

When I try to arrive to this expression from the definition of fouriet transform, I got

\begin{equation}
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-T}^{T} U(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt=\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{T}e^{-j\omega t} dt=
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \left[ \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{-j\omega}\right]_0^T \\
= \frac{1}{j\omega} - \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{e^{-j\omega T}}{j\omega}\right]=\frac{1}{j\omega} - \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\left[ \frac{\cos(\omega T)}{j\omega}\right] +\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega} \right]
\end{equation}

We know that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\omega} \right] = \pi \delta(\omega)
\end{equation}

My question is, how can we show that

\begin{equation}
x(\omega)=\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\left[ \frac{\cos(\omega T)}{j\omega}\right] = 0\\
\end{equation}

in some distributional sense?

Given a compact-support test function $\phi(\omega)$, we can write

\begin{equation}
\int x(\omega) \phi(\omega) d\omega = \int_{|\omega|<\epsilon} x(\omega) \phi(\omega) d\omega + \int_{|\omega|>\epsilon} x(\omega) \phi(\omega) d\omega
\end{equation}

it is not hard to see that as $T \rightarrow \infty$ the 2nd integral on the right-hand side of the above equation will become zero by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. But what about the 1st integral? Can we say that as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $\phi(\omega)$ will become "almost constant" and will come out of the integral?, ie

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{|\omega|<\epsilon} x(\omega) \phi(\omega) d\omega = \phi(0) \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{|\omega|<\epsilon} x(\omega) d\omega=0
\end{equation}
as $x(\omega)$ is an odd function?

If so, what will happen if the boundary of the test function is at $\omega=0$?

Comment: Technical remark: we work with [tempered distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) here, so test functions are not necessarily compactly supported: they come from the Schwartz class.

Comment: See [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step/4111722#4111722) for a rigorous development.

Answer (score 3):

Given a test function $\phi$, decompose it into even part $\phi_e(\omega)=\frac12(\phi(\omega)+\phi(-\omega))$ and odd part $\phi_o(\omega)=\frac12(\phi(\omega)-\phi(-\omega))$ and odd part. So, $\phi=\phi_e+\phi_o$. We have
$$
\int \frac{\cos \omega   T}{j \omega} \phi_e(\omega)\,d\omega = 0
$$
by symmetry.

Since $\phi_o(0)=0$, we can write $\phi_o(\omega)=\omega \psi(\omega)$ where $\psi$ is [another test function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541046/147263). Hence
$$
\int \frac{\cos \omega   T}{j \omega} \phi_o(\omega)\,d\omega =
\frac{1}{j} \int  \cos (\omega   T) \psi(\omega)\,d\omega
$$
which tends to zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: I believe this solves the problem. An extremely clean and neat solution..