# Half-Fourier transform, relation to Delta function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, complex-integration, dirac-delta

so the Fourier transform of the Kronecker Delta function is (up to sign conventions / normalisation)

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\; e^{i t \omega} = \delta(\omega).$$

Can one say anything about the half-Fourier transform

$$\int_0^\infty dt\; e^{i t \omega}$$

and its relation to the Kronecker Delta function?

Specifically, I have come across the relation

$$\int_0^\infty dt\; \textrm{Re}[e^{i t \omega}]  \;\;\Big(=\int_0^\infty dt \cos( t \omega)\Big) \;\;= \delta (\omega),$$

but cannot seem to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: It is strange to see \textrm{cos} with manually added space before it.  If you just write \cos then it appears without italics and with the conventional spacing before and after it in expressions like $a\cos b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I believe that [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856337/fourier-transform-of-unit-step-function) and its answer completely answer your question.

Comment: @MattL,Thanks for the link. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a factor $\frac 12$ is missing in the last equation.

$$\int_{\mathbb R}e^{itw}dt=\delta(w),$$hence
$$\Re \int_{\mathbb R}e^{itw}dt=  \int_{\mathbb R}\Re e^{itw}dt=\Re  \delta(w) = \delta(w).$$

Then again, $\Re e^{itw} = \cos (tw) = \cos (-tw) =\Re e^{-itw} $, hence
$$  \int_{\mathbb R}\Re e^{itw}dt=2\int_{0}^\infty\Re e^{itw}dt =  \delta(w),$$therefore
$$ \int_{0}^\infty\Re e^{itw}dt = \frac 12 \delta(w).$$

Comment: Thank you... That clears it up.