# Fourier transform of $\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(t)\, dt$

Tags: fourier-analysis

How to prove   that

> $$\mathcal{F}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(\tau)\, d\tau\right\}=\frac{1}{i\omega}F(\omega)+\pi F(0)\delta(\omega),$$

where $F(\omega)$ is Fourier transform of $f(t)$. 
Could anyone explain to me how to prove this?

thanks.

Comment: In general, we cannot assign meaning to $\mathscr{F}\{u*f\}$. 

For example, if $f(t)=u(t)$, then $u*u=tu(t)$.  I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825297/fourier-transform-of-t-ht/2825495#2825495) that in  distribution 

$$\mathscr{F}\{ u*u\}=\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)+i\pi \delta'(\omega)\tag1$$

where $\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)$ is the distributional derivative of $\text{PV}\left(\frac1{\omega}\right)$.

The right-hand side is ***not*** equal to $\pi F(\omega)\delta(\omega)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to look at it is to note that

$$\int_{-\infty}^tf(\tau)d\tau=(f\star u)(t)\tag{1}$$

where $\star$ denotes convolution, and $u(t)$ is the unit step function. Consequently, the Fourier transform of $(1)$ is

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(\tau)\, d\tau\right\}=F(\omega)U(\omega)\tag{2}$$

where $F(\omega)$ and $U(\omega)$ are the Fourier transforms of $f(t)$ and $u(t)$, respectively. The Fourier transform of $u(t)$ is

$$U(\omega)=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{i\omega}\tag{3}$$

A discussion of $(3)$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856337/fourier-transform-of-unit-step-function). With $(3)$, $(2)$ can be written as

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(\tau)\, d\tau\right\}=\pi F(\omega)\delta(\omega)+\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}=\pi F(0)\delta(\omega)+\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}\tag{4}$$

Comment: @Dear Matt L., Thank you for reading and taking the time for the great responses. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @MattL.  Hi Matt. In general, we cannot assign meaning to $\mathscr{F}\{u*f\}$. 

For example, if $f(t)=u(t)$, then $u*u=tu(t)$.  I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825297/fourier-transform-of-t-ht/2825495#2825495) that in  distribution 

$$\mathscr{F}\{ u*u\}=\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)+i\pi \delta'(\omega)\tag1$$

where $\left(-\frac1{\omega^2}\right)$ is the distributional derivative of $\text{PV}\left(\frac1{\omega}\right)$.

The right-hand side is ***not*** equal to $\pi F(\omega)\delta(\omega)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{F(\omega)}{i\omega}\right)$.

Comment: @mattl.  I'm not sure if you had a chance to read my comment.  Please let me know.

Comment: @MarkViola: Yes, I need to check, but one should add certain conditions on $f(t)$ for this relation to be true. Obviously, $F(0)$ must exist, and moreover, $F(\omega)$ must exist in the conventional sense, not as a distribution.