# Shifting a smooth function of compact support

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

> Let $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an infinitely differentiable function of compact support.  Define $$\psi (x) :=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\varphi (x) - \varphi (0)}{x},  & \text{$x \neq 0$} \\
> \varphi'(0), & \text{$x = 0$}
> \end{cases}. $$
>
> **Is $\psi$ be infinitely differentiable and compactly supported?**

Some context: $\psi$ is given as a hint to prove that for a distribution $f$ with the property $xf = 0$ (in the sense of distributions), $f = C \delta_0$, for some constant $C$.  If $\psi$ has the appropriate properties, then the proof for the main question follows quickly.  After some tinkering, however, I am not convinced that $\psi$ has  either necessary property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\psi$ is $C^\infty$-smooth because [Quotient of two smooth functions is smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541046/).

If $\varphi(0)=0$, then $\psi$ has compact support, because in this case $\psi(x)=0$ whenever $\varphi(x)=0$.

But if $\varphi(0)\ne 0$, then $\psi $ does not have compact support. Indeed, for large enough $x$ we have $\varphi(x)=0$ and therefore $\psi(x)=-\varphi(0)/x$.

Comment: I've learned since posting this question that the hint is flawed.  But thanks for the insight anyways.